# regular expressions irregularities in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I see allot of information about regular expressions but fail to find the solution to my problem. I hope this is not been covered before. As usual I am not all that interested in getting the solution, but rather understanding why it works the way it does. Only this way I can learn bash and all it's complexities.

My example:

```
#!/bin/bash
Stext="Hallo World"
re="(.[a-z]*)$"
[[ $Stext =~ $re ]]
DBTable=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo $DBTable
DBTable=`expr "$Stext" : $re`
echo $DBTable
```

as most of you can guess, I am NOT getting ***World*** printed out twice, and I don't know why.

So far I have manage to get some response out of the expr version in escaping the expression to:

```
DBTable=`expr "$Stext" : '\(.[a-z]*\)$'`
```

This still does not yield the expected result.

Can anybody give me some insight on this please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expr` treats the regex as implicitly anchored at the start of the string — that is, it implicitly adds a `^` — so you need to provide everything before the point of interest. Additionally, as you've noticed, you need to write `\(` and `\)` rather than `(` and `)`, since `expr` uses Basic Regular Expressions (BREs), not Extended Regular Expressions (EREs). So, this:

```
expr 'Hallo World' : '.[a-z]* \(.[a-z]*\)$'
```

will print `World`.

Comment: Brilliant, now I know about BRE and ERE. Thanks a million @ruakh

Comment: Note that "implicitly anchored" is the way regular expressions are **defined**.  A regular expression denotes a set of strings, not a search pattern.  The "grep behavior" is implemented by taking a regex and then applying it at successive positions in the input until it finds a match. If you don't do that, then the regex just tells you "this input matches me" or "this input does not".